# An empty metal container (without its handle) weight 15%

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

An empty metal container (without its handle) weight 15% of its weight when filled with a particular liquid. After adding the handle, the weight of the fully filled container increases by 5%. If the weight of a partly filled container is 1/3 of the completely filled container with handle attached, then what fraction of container is utilized?

a) 4/17

b) 3/17

c) 6/19

d) 3/19

My equations are:

$e=0.15W$

$e+h+L=1.05 \cdot 0.15W$

$0.5L+e=1/3(e+L+h)$

$e$ is weight of empty container without handle,

$h$ is weight of the handle of the container,

$L$ is the weight of the liquid inside the container.

$W$ is weight of utilised container.

How can equation of four variables be solved by three equations?

Or are there any other approach?

Comment: Well, you are only asked to deduce one value, you don't need to fully solve it.  So, it might be possible.

Comment: I think you have that $e+L=W.$

Comment: Think about it the way an elementary student would think about it. Suppose a full container w/o the handle weighed 100g, then the container would weigh 15g and the liquid 85g. Adding a handle adds 5%, or 5 grams, so a full container with a handle would weight 15g+85g+5g=105g. One third of this total is 35g, subtracting the container and the handle we have 35g - 5g - 15g = 15g, giving a fraction of $\frac{15g}{85g}=\frac{3}{17}$.